# Selecting maximum and minimum values after performing a groupby for multiple columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some temperature data in the form of a table 'weather_data' with the following fields:

```
Month   Day   Element   Data_Value
4       12    TMAX         53     
4       08    TMAX         62     
4       12    TMAX         78     
4       12    TMIN        -32     
4       12    TMIN        -12
```

What I wish to have is the max and min values after performing groupby for the elements [Month, Day, Element]:

```
Month   Day   Element   Data_Value
4       12    TMAX         78     
              TMIN        -32     
4       08    TMAX         62
```

I ran the code

```
weather_data.groupby(['Month','Day','Element'])['Data_Value']
```

But only got output where first value per TMAX and TMIN is picked up (instead of picking up the max TMAX and min TMIN per day of the month):

```
Month   Day   Element   Data_Value
4       12    TMAX         53     
              TMIN        -32     
4       08    TMAX         62
```

Please tell me what additional commands I need to add to get my desired output.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
max = df.loc[df['Element'] == 'TMAX'].groupby(['Month','Day','Element'])['Data_Value'].max()
min = df.loc[df['Element'] == 'TMIN'].groupby(['Month','Day','Element'])['Data_Value'].min()

pd.concat([max, min]).reset_index()

out:


    Month   Day Element Data_Value
0   4   8   TMAX    62
1   4   12  TMAX    78
2   4   12  TMIN    -32
```

Answer (score 0):

check with

```
df['Func']=df.Element.map({'TMAX':'max','TMIN':'min'})
pd.concat([y.groupby(['Month','Day','Element'])['Data_Value'].agg(x) for x , y in df.groupby('Func')])
Month  Day  Element
4      8    TMAX       62
       12   TMAX       78
            TMIN      -32
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```